# how put blur event on particular id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put a blur function on a particular id. What i am doing wrong here ? I want to write a function when user in test 1 of tab1 press the tab key, it will blur the tab 1 and activate the tab 2 :

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='tab1' class="tabss">
    <ul class= "set2"> 
        <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox ID="test1" runat="server" /></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab2' class="tabss">
    <ul class= "set2"> 
        <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='tab3' class="tabss">
    <ul class= "set"> 

        <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox  runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$('#last').blur(function () {    
    alert("test");
});
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5fL/4/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Which element has id="last"??

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LCb7x/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny its not working. When it move into second tab.it is not moving into third

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$("#itemId").mouseenter(function () {
    alert ("mouse entered");
}).mouseleave(function () {      
    alert("mouse leave");
});
```

`.blur` will work for input fields only.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its clear now that you want to navigate to the next tab after the user loses focus of the last text box in each tab. therefore you can do something like this:

```
$('.tabss').each(function() { 

    $('input:last',this).blur(function () {
        alert('tab done!');
   })

});
```

Here is the fiddle (with multiple inputs): http://jsfiddle.net/2TH8K/1/

Here is another fiddle, updated to your original example (note that I replaced ASP.NET textboxes with html textboxes)
http://jsfiddle.net/4n5fL/7/

Comment: i want to put blur on <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox ID="test1" runat="server" /></li>

Comment: @user3149053 .blur() is when an object loses .focus() http://api.jquery.com/focus/ Implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links

Comment: @Wayne: here link and test box is available then what is the problem?

Comment: This will work fine for as many inputs you have on the page, make sure each set of inputs are in div with class="tabss" and the event will fire on the last input for each set (see updated fiddle with multiple inputs)

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs a.active span {
    color: #BF0404;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 19px 12px 8px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a span {
    height: 34px;
}
.tabss{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}

        <ul class='tabs'>
                                <li class="firsttab"><a href='#tab1'><span>Step 1</span></a></li>
                                <li class="secondtab"><a href='#tab2'><span>Step 2</span></a></li>
    <li class="thirdtab"><a href='#tab2'><span>Step 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            $('.tabs li.firsttab a').addClass('active');
            $('#tab1').fadeIn();
            $('#tab2').fadeOut();
            $('#tab3').fadeOut();
            }



            $('.tabs li.firsttab a').click(function () {
                $('.tabs li.firsttab a').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('#tab1').fadeIn();
                $('#tab2').fadeOut();
                $('#tab3').hide();

          });


            $('.tabs li.secondtab a').click(function () {
                $('.tabs li.secondtab a').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

                $('#tab1').hide();
                $('#tab2').fadeIn();
           });
```

You need to add event for third tab click also. I hope this should give you good start on fixing your requirement.

Comment: can u do this in jsfiddle

Comment: Check out the fiddle and implement accordingly. In above code i have just shared portion of the code, from where you can start implementing things. Better use the fiddle.